# Gmail and Content-Type: message/partial

Tags: gmail

I've received an email in three parts, as the sender must have thought the attached PDF file (of 84KB) was somewhat large.. The parts are annotated with `Content-Type: message/partial`. Gmail appears to be unable to deal with this; the contents of the message itself is displayed properly when opening the first email, but the attachment is not available for download in one piece.

I've since reconstructed the PDF by viewing the source, concatenating the contents and base64-decoding, but I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

Or is `message/partial` something we should all quickly forget about?

Comment: It sounds like a flaw in the sending email client/system and probably not something that you can do anything about. You might try forwarding the message to another email account (e.g. Yahoo, Outlook.com) but I wouldn't hold out much hope.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the sender is at fault, I was just wondering if there is a way to fix it in Gmail. I can read the mail when I inspect its source, so that's fine for me, but that's a bit unusable for family members that are 'less technically inclined'..

Comment: Within Gmail? No, not really. A third-party client (Thunderbird, et al.) might be able to repair it, but esoteric stuff like that is far beyond what Gmail's web interface offers.